# Why is my animation deleted before rendering?

Tags: python, matplotlib-animation

I try to animated live data. It used to work but now it does not. I have the following code:

```
import subprocess
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def plot(i):  
    print(1)
    MyOut = subprocess.Popen("pytr portfolio",
                
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout,stderr = MyOut.communicate()

    chart_data = []
    days = []
    t = 0
    new_char = stdout.split()
    netValue = float(new_char[new_char.index(b'netValue') + 2])

    file = open('netValue.txt','a')
    file.write(str(netValue)) 
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()

    file = open('netValue.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        t += 1
        chart_data.append(float(line))
        days.append(t)
    file.close()
    print(days)
    plt.cla()


    plt.plot(days,chart_data)
   

    plt.title('depot_performance')

    plt.show()

plot = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), plot, 1000)
```

It says: "UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()" but I use plt.show()".

What could be the reason to this?